# How to check if the standard input is empty?

Tags: c#, console

I need to know if there are any input symbols in the standard input.

But I don't know how to check such a condition.

As I understand I can't use Console.Read() because it will actually read the next input symbol.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `standard input`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to restrict the input to a range of valid characters?

Comment: Do you wanna check if the user has provided with you with an input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use `Console.In` as an `System.IO.TextReader` and use the `Peek()`-Method:

```
if(Console.In.Peek() == "I don't know what it will be...")
{ /* Do something */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.writeline();
var a = console.readline();
if(a == null)
{
do something..
}
else
{
do something..
}
```

Comment: this is not functionally equivalent - if there is no input then `ReadLine` will block the thread. Checking if the input is empty is used to prevent blocking

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Console.In.Peek()!=-1) //solves the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to check if there's any data waiting on the console's standard input without actually reading it, I'd suggest You go with something like this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()))
{
    //check if there are any characters on the input stream
    if(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        //do whatever You want to do when the stream is not empty
    }
    else
    {
        //do whatever You want to do when the stream is empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I undestood your question, you can try something like this:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
{
 // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
 string s = Console.ReadLine();
   if (s.Contains('@') Or s.Contains('!')) // you can add other symobols as need
   {
   //do your work

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what type of input your user had inserted then you can use something like this if your **symbols** refers to **"<,>,?,/,@,#,$,%,^,&,etc..."**
these links can help you out [Validation of input fields](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/30/10-examples-of-basic-input-validation-in-javascript/)and [this one](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/30/10-examples-of-basic-input-validation-in-javascript/)
and

> please frame your question properly it is difficult to understand what
>   you are asking